# Expand path under cursor in VIM

Tags: linux, vim, debian, path

I often find myself needing to lookup what the exact path to a file is when programming with VIM (in insert mode, like giving an image path inside my source code), even though I know what the path roughly is.

So I was wondering if there was some sort of "expand path" feature/plugin for VIM that could do this for me, similar to the tab completion in a shell?

Comment: Control r % may work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of plugins for Vim that will help you find files given incomplete or "fuzzy" names or paths, but if all you need is shell-like path completion, that feature is built in. Just start typing the path, relative or absolute, then type Ctrl-X Ctrl-F. Vim will complete as much of the name as it can, then show you a list of possible completions than can be selected using Ctrl-N and Ctrl-P. See

```
:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough about what I meant - I meant something that completes a path in insert mode. See my updated question. For this kind of completion I use the CtrlP plugin.

Comment: I guess I don't understand then. Ctrl-X Ctrl-F _does_ complete a path in insert mode, just like tab completion does in the shell. In any case, in addition to CtrlP there is Command-T and FuzzyFinder.

Comment: Oh. I only skimmed your text, this actually is exactly what I wanted. Sorry for the confusion :/